# Spring Boot + Hibernate + MySQL Unable to create initial connections of pool

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Below is my pom.xml which I copied from most of the tutorials in the internet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.com.froggy</groupId>
    <artifactId>froggy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>My Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Then, below is the configuration I placed in my properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test 
spring.datasource.username = root 
spring.datasource.password = 

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true 
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000 
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

What could have been my mistake? I got the following error:

> 2016-09-25 22:58:18.297  INFO 8452 --- [           main]
>   org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core
>   {5.0.11.Final} 2016-09-25 22:58:18.299  INFO 8452 --- [
>   main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded
>   properties from resource hibernate.properties:
>   {spring.datasource.username=root,
>   spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true,
>   spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=60000,
>   spring.datasource.password=,
>   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test,
>   hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false,
>   spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1,
>   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop} 2016-09-25 22:58:18.300 
>   INFO 8452 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
>   : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist 2016-09-25
>   22:58:18.353  INFO 8452 --- [           main]
>   o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate
>   Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 2016-09-25 22:58:19.706 ERROR 8452
>   --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:341)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
>   ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:143)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
>   [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>   [hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>   [spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
>   [spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
>   [spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
>   [spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
>   [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
>   [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>   [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   my.com.froggy.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: connect  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:300)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]     ... 59 common frames
>   omitted
>
> 2016-09-25 22:58:19.708  WARN 8452 --- [           main]
>   o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain
>   connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>   2016-09-25 22:58:19.711  WARN 8452 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] 2016-09-25
>   22:58:19.714  INFO 8452 --- [           main]
>   o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
>   2016-09-25 22:58:19.726  INFO 8452 --- [           main]
>   utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2016-09-25
>   22:58:19.729 ERROR 8452 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
>   [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]     at
>   my.com.froggy.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException:
>   Unable to create requested service
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]   ... 16 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]   ... 32 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: You sure MySQL is running and accepting connections? Doesn't look like it is...

Comment: @BoristheSpider How can I ensure that MySQL is running ad accepting connections?

Comment: I would suggest checking.

Comment: Do I need MySQL server installed on my machine? I was thinking spring boot will take care of this matter. Am I wrong on this part?

Comment: Sorry to say you are wrong. If you want an embedded database you will have to use something like [hypersonic](http://hsqldb.org/) or [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/). Spring Boot [supports these out of the box](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-embedded-database-support).

Comment: Let me first install the db server and get back to you. Should I be able to confirm that this is the cause, I'll give you an up vote. :) thanks mate!

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have MYSQL installed. If it is installed, make sure it is configured to port 3306. Also if it is still not connecting make sure your password and name are entered properly. Looks like you haven't provided password for username root in `application.properties`.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=12345
```

And make sure you have created that database manually first.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you missed to configure the URL correctly. MYSQL is available on port 3306; however, in your url, you did not note that port.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have put the wrong URL.

It should be `spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:port_number/db_name` 
(you have to put your port number and database name)

Every time your server will not run in port 3306. Because If you are using XAMPP server, Some times that port number has been taken that port number. Then your MySQL port number would be another number. Then please check it out. I have attached some S
If you are using MySQL Workbench.
[image: Manage Server Connections]